# Hide 1st, 3rd, 4th, 6th, 7th, 9th, 10th, 12th div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following array, which are elements within a html page:

```
["1", "1", "1","2", "2", "2","3", "3", "3","4", "4", "4",];
```

More specifically these are divs:

```
<div class="abc1">1</div>
<div class="abc2">1</div>
<div class="abc3">1</div>
<div class="abc4">2</div>
<div class="abc5">2</div>
<div class="abc6">2</div>
<div class="abc7">3</div>
<div class="abc8">3</div>
<div class="abc9">3</div>
<div class="abc10">4</div>
<div class="abc11">4</div>
<div class="abc12">4</div>
```

I want to hide the 1st, 3rd, 4th, 6th, 7th, 9th, 10th, 12th div.

I tried this code but it only hides every odd number.

```
$(document).ready(hideLabelFF);

function hideLabelFF(){
$('*[class^="abc"]').each(function (i){
    $('*[class^="abc"]:nth-of-type(2n+1)').hide();
});
};
```

Comment: you don't need javascript, your div already has specific class assigned to it, why don't you use that instead?

Comment: can't you try with css ? div:nth-child(1),div:nth-child(3),div:nth-child(4) {
    visibility:hidden;
} so, on?

Comment: `$('.abc1, .abc3, .abc4, .abc6, .abc7, .abc9, .abc10, .abc12').hide();`

Answer (score 3):

With **2n+1**, you are targetting **odd divs**. You have 2 series one is 1,4,7,10... and the other is 3,6,9,12...

Simply try following

```
function hideLabelFF(){
    $('*[class^="abc"]:nth-of-type(3n+1)').hide();
    $('*[class^="abc"]:nth-of-type(3n)').hide();
}
```

For reference - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NfiBTcK12xfqhzj7VqLC?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the purpose of this action is; sounds like a homework assignment to find the smartest way to do this.

The most straightforward way would be this:

```
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12].forEach(num => $(`.abc${num}`).hide());
```

It's not smart though. You've already noticed a pattern there. The shown elements are 2, 5, 8, 11, i.e. 3n-1. You can therefore do this:

```
$('*[class^="abc"]:nth-of-type(3n-2)').hide();
$('*[class^="abc"]:nth-of-type(3n)').hide();
```

inverse the hiding:

```
$('*[class^="abc"]').hide();
$('*[class^="abc"]:nth-of-type(3n-1)').show();
```

or finally, use the `.not()` method to bring this all to a one-liner:

```
$('*[class^="abc"]').not(":nth-of-type(3n-1)").hide();
```

Comment: Glad that you answered with all possible solutions!

Comment: I'm fairly sure they're not all solutions yet ;)